# clob to xmltype: converting " to &quote

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltype

I am converting clob to xmltype in plsql as below.
`xml xmltype := xmltype(Input);`

Input variables contains the text as below

```
<request xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <comment>Hello, this is "james"</comment>
</request>
```

After the xmltype conversion the text is changed to `Hello, this is &quot;james&quot;"`

When tried to extract the xml from xmltype I need to extract the text as `Hello, this is "james"`.

Answer (score 1):

[Xmlcast](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions224.htm#SQLRF20012)

```
select xmlcast(xmltype('<request xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <comment>Hello, this is "james"</comment>
</request>').extract('/request/comment/text()') as varchar2(100) ) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

just especify the charset like this: XMLTYPE(Input,NLS_CHARSET_ID('AL32UTF8'))